# jquery if elseif control shortcut

Tags: html, jquery

I have a radio input and whichever is chosen I make "#mains" removeclass and addclass, but the conditions will be too high. How can I make the conditions properly. ?

For now, I am just deleting "navbar-sticky" and I will write conditions for reverse situations. There will be very long conditions for it. Thank you in advance for your assistants.

```
let navbar_type = $('input[name=navbar-type]')


navbar_type.on('click', function () {
        let navbarChecked = $(this).val();

        if (navbarChecked === 'hidden')
            $('#mains').removeClass("navbar-sticky").addClass("menu-hidden")
        else if (navbarChecked === 'static')
            $('#mains').removeClass("navbar-sticky").addClass("navbar-static")
        else if (navbarChecked === 'floating')
            $('#mains').removeClass("navbar-sticky").addClass("navbar-floating")
        else
            $('#mains').removeClass("navbar-sticky").addClass("navbar-sticky")
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` accept strings that are space-separated lists of classes.

`data-` attributes let you attach data to elements. This can be used to determine what class a particular radio button controls.

Remove all classes, then add the one of interest.

```js
const $target = $('.target');
const $display = $('.display');
const $colors = $('input[type=radio][name=color]');
const classes = $colors.map((i,e) => e.dataset.class).toArray().join(' ');
$colors.on('change', evnt => {
  $target.removeClass(classes).addClass(evnt.target.dataset.class);
  $display.html($(evnt.target).val());
});
```

```css
.red { background: red; }
.green { background: green; }
.blue { background: cyan; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="display">red</div>
<div class="target red">
<input type="radio" name="color" value="red" data-class="red" checked>
<label for="red">Red</label>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="green" data-class="green">
<label for="green">Green</label>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" data-class="blue">
<label for="red">Blue</label>
</div>
```

Comment: It is good with the selected you said, but how do I print the checked one at the beginning of the page?

Comment: With reference to my example, `$('input[type=radio][name=color]:checked')` would get you the element for the button that is marked. If you had an element to use for that, you could use something like `$someElement.html($('input[type=radio][name=color]:checked').val())` to set its content to the checked value. I've updated my example to add that feature.

Answer (score 1):

```
let navbar_type = $('input[name=navbar-type]');
navbar_type.on('click', function () {
    let currentValue = $(this).val();
    if (currentValue === 'sticky') {
       return;
    }
    $('#mains').removeClass("navbar-sticky").addClass("navbar-" + currentValue);

});
```