# jquery body map use of addclass removeclass

Tags: jquery

I have an option, whichever I choose I can change from "#mains" with map. but I wanted to change that. and I want to print body, but body.map does not work. removeclass doesn't work when doing addclass. Thank you in advance for your help.

**body to array returns empty**

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" id="vertical" name="page-type" value="vertical" class="neon-input-radio" checked="" data-class="menu-vertical">
    <span class="neon-label">Vertical</span>
    <input type="radio" id="horizontal" name="page-type" value="horizontal" class="neon-input-radio" data-class="menu-horizontal">
    <span class="neon-label">Horizontal</span>
</div>
```

old

```
const $mains = $('#mains')
const $page_type = $('input[name=page-type]');
const pageClass = $page_type.map((i, e) => e.dataset.class).toArray().join(' ');
$page_type.on('change', evnt => {
     $mains.removeClass(pageClass).addClass(evnt.target.dataset.class);
 });
```

new(ERROR)

```
!function (e, n, a) {
    "use strict";
    var i = a("body");

const pageClass = i.map((i, e) => e.dataset.class).toArray().join(' ');
    a("input[name=page-type]").on("change", (evnt => {
            console.log(pageClass)
            i.removeClass(pageClass).addClass(evnt.target.dataset.class);
        }
    ))
}(window, document, jQuery);
```

Comment: You old and new code do different things. Is that what you want ? Does the `body` have `data` attribute ?

Comment: I want a body .body to array.

Comment: please post the relevant HTML (*for the new script*)

Comment: I want to do the following, for example, when "menu-vertical" changes in body class, I want to change it to menu-horizontal. or vice versa

Comment: So, body is a single element what do you want to `map` ?

Comment: ```<body class="menu-vertical navbar-sticky footer-static"></body>```

There are 6 different color options for the "map" theme color. If else is done on each of them it will be too long.

(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65448843/jquery-if-elseif-control-shortcut/65449005#65449005)

"body" shape of the answer I received from here